# Lucene in Java, C#.Net and C++. Which is the best version for long-term use on Windows server?

Tags: lucene, lucene.net, clucene

I am going to implement Lucene search into my project and I want to make a best start.
So I consider between 3 versions of Lucene (Java/C#.Net/C++) which is the best version upon these criterias :

**1.performance

2.easy to implement

3.plenty of documents** ?

Assume the system is Window server, and I ask it for a long-term use.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unless you've got a specific feature you need, I would look at best being:

a) Whatever platform you are developing the program in -- there are lots of advantages to not having to switch tools/contexts/platforms to muck around with the search internals.

b) Whatever platform your ops guys want to deal with -- I know lots of windows ops guys hate dealing with java as it is a strange foreign language. For example.

c) All of the above being equal, Java is the real flagship lucene project that everyone else is keeping up with with and that has the most tools & resources. It is the way to go if you don't have any reason not to use java. Solr is another advantage here -- you can pretty easily use a pre-wrapped fully functional lucene http server.

In any case, keep in mind that at least theoretically any lucene index written on one platform is readable by others so you don't necessarily have to fully commit to a single platform.

Answer (score 4):

I would say Java. Lucene was initially developed in Java and I would think there are bigger community, more documentation and bigger deployments using Java.

Granted, Windows is not usually considered as primary platform for deploying Java services but it still would work with flying colors. Many people using Windows for Java development and even deployment so I don't expect any major issues.

Comment: stackoverflow uses lucene.net, I would call that a big deployment.

Comment: As far as I know [from stackoverflow podcast] they considering or already switching to Java for search (Solr or Elastic search, if I recall correctly).